# Loading JavaScript files using Helmet not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

I am trying to use Helmet to load javascript files but it does not seem to work. I tried various paths like './vendor','../vendor' '/vendor' and it did not work. Here is what I have. Thanks a lot.

```
function DashboardLayout(props) {
    return (
        <Fragment>
        <Helmet>
           <title>Dashboard</title>
            <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
            <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
            <script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
            <script src="./vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
            <script src="./vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
            <script src="./js/sb-admin-2.min.js" type="text/javascript" />          
         </Helmet>
           {props.children}
     </Fragment>
      );
  }
```

and the folder directories.

[image]

Comment: what does the network tab in devtools say? 404?

Comment: Noted and thanks for the reminder to use network tab dev tools.

Comment: Not enough information. What is your HTTP server? Nginx? Webpack dev server?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I got it working already. Basically, I just need to place the JS files in the public folder.